# When dropping non significant variable (p-value > .4), $R^2$ drops a lot. What can be the reason?

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, econometrics, inference, r-squared

I have a linear model with 7 regressors, where 2 are statistically non significant (p-value > 0.4), with 40 observations. The model has not indication of multicollinearity (tolerances and VIF were accounted for) nor heterocedasticity.

However, when I try to remove one of the non significant regressors, the $R^2$ of the model drops a lot (from 0.7 to 0.4).

What can be the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Is there any missing data? That is, does the sample size increase when you drop this variable? You say you have 40 cases but are you sure that the model with the variable has 40 cases and is not affected by listwise deletion based on missing data?

Comment: It is helpfull to show your model. There are many open ends. For instance: How did you test the significance of those variables, and if If you did Anova which type of sums did you use and what is the F-score and what degrees of freedoms change?

Comment: With N as low as 40, a fairly important covariate can be nonsignificant. They could also be acting as mediators.

Answer (score 6):

It's apples and oranges. A covariate with a high $p$-value can still increase $R^2$ by a good amount, because more goes into the test that produces the $p$-value than just the increase in proportion of variance accounted for.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the predictors in question include cases that exert a lot of *leverage* or *influence*.  These likely outliers could be contributing a deceptively large amount to the magnitude of coefficients and the model's overall fit.  RSQ could indeed by inflated by such cases, when there is no consistent pattern by which a higher value for the predictor is accompanied by a higher (or lower) value for the outcome.  The mechanism that calculates *p*-values will "recognize" such a situation.